# Possible to sort an XML by attribute before turning it into an array?

Tags: c#, xml, arrays

Here is my current code that gets the elements from the xml and puts it into an array.  But it just puts it in the order it reads it (top to bottom)

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

// XML Path
var doc = XDocument.Load("C:/Scripts/example.xml");

// Node
string[] picks = doc.Descendants("pick").Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();
```

I want to know if it is possible to sort the array by an attribute (in this case, "order") as I turn it into an array.  The desired output being {Gragas, Draven, Ryze, Shen, Shyvanna, ...}

here's my xml:

```
<championSelect>
<blue>
  <pick order="1">Gragas</pick>
  <pick order="4">Shen</pick>
  <pick order="5">Shyvanna</pick>
  <pick order="8">Garen</pick>
  <pick order="9">Karthus</pick>
</blue>
<red>
  <pick order="2">Draven</pick>
  <pick order="3">Ryze</pick>
  <pick order="6">Ahri</pick>
  <pick order="7">Annie</pick>
  <pick order="10">Brand</pick>
</red>
```

I was playing with OrderBy() and OrderByDescending() with little luck

Comment: Why not use OrderBy before .ToArray?

Comment: Turn it into an array then sort it. It makes a lot more sense to sort an array than it does to sort XML (which might be possible using some abstraction like LINQ to XML but isn't noramlly and doesn't make sense).

Comment: @evanmcdonnal turning it into an array first won't work here because the OP wants to sort on a value which won't be in the final array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `OrderBy` extension method

```
string[] picks = doc
  .Descendants("pick")
  .OrderBy(element => Int32.Parse(element.GetAttribute("order").Value))
  .Select(element => element.Value)
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 but it should be `OrderBy(element => Int32.Parse(element.Attribute("order").Value)` I think.

Comment: @keyboardP i believe i'm correct.  The `GetAttribute` method returns ` string` while `GetAttributeNode` returns a `AttributeNode` type.  On that method I would need to call `Value`.

Comment: @keyboardP here is the MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7.aspx

Comment: `element` is of type XElement and not XmlElement as `Descendants` returns XElements.

Comment: @keyboardP ah yes you are correct.  I was reading `XmlDocument` and not `XDocument`.  I will update

Comment: No problem, +1 anyway as it was pretty much there :)